# Regex in java: find all _overlapping_ variants (ab)|(bc)|(de)|(f) in abcdef

Tags: java, regex

If I run this regex in java I'll receive {ab, de, f}, but I would like to receive
{ab, bc, de, f}. I think that bc can't be received because bc has overlapping letter with ab. How to change the default behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism which is zero-width so each test it performs resets cursor to position before test was performed.

Just iterate over all places between characters and check if after it exist substring matching your regex. You can place this substring in capturing group and access it later.

```
String input = "abcdef";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?=(ab)|(bc)|(de)|(f))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()){
    for (int i=1; i<=m.groupCount(); i++){
        if (m.group(i)!=null) 
            System.out.println("group ("+i+") -> "+m.group(i));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
group (1) -> ab
group (2) -> bc
group (3) -> de
group (4) -> f
```

Comment: Don't you need the /g flag in javascript to capture more than one group?

Comment: @AR7 If my eyes are not playing tricks on me, then, this question is about Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Pshermo My apologies! My eyes were ones playing tricks on me. Good answer haha.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I have to determine which group (number) succeeded in every case. For example ab -> 1 bc -> 2 de ->3 f -> 4. How to do it?

Comment: @Curiosity You can simply place each part in separate group and check which one is not empty (null). I updated my code a little to show what I mean.