# Regex in java: find all the groups (?=(ab)|(abc)) in abcdef

Tags: java, regex

If I run this Regex in Java I'll receive `{ab}`, but I would like to receive `{ab, abc}`. It's similar to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28651182/regex-in-java-find-all-overlapping-variants-abbcdef-in-abcdef%20,)

But I want to find similar groups as well.

Comment: Based on your comment from vks answer your question looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So consider editing it and describing what problem you are trying to solve, what input is possible and what output should be expected (preferably with explanation why such output is correct and not other).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy fix is

```
(?=((ab)c))
```

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/17)

or

```
(?=(ab))(abc)
```

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/iS6jF6/18)

Comment: It works but I have a thousands autogenerated patterns compiled in one regex. This abc is just a very simple example, I have much complex subpatterns with a lot of metacharacters. Is there any way to do your operation with standard behavior? If it's not possible I can convert my subpatterns but this can be a very difficult work.

Comment: @Curiosity the only wya it seems would be the first option ie club the similar ones together.Once an engine goes forward ,it cannot come back